# replace UI in a button click while UI is generated by PHP in advance

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a block of html code that's being generated by PHP function that's executed using an ajax request, and I want to add to this html a toggle button that will change several fields in the this block of UI (and also the text inside the button itself).

My idea was to create the new fields within the same PHP function but with `display=none` and have a css class to the fields e.g `.new` to all of the new fields and `.old` to the old fields that shouldn't appear, then hide all of the `.old` fields and display the new ones (and vise versa) using JS function when the button is clicked.

another approach is to build another similar PHP function to build the new UI (even though most of the elements are similar) and the new button will have an `onclick` function that makes an ajax call to run the corresponding PHP function.

I'm not sure which is the right approach in this case, or is there a simpler/better solution.

would appreciate any feedback.
if any additional info is needed let me know.

Comment: Re: _"I'm not sure which is the right approach"_ Ultimately, it's whichever approach you decide is right for what you are architecting. But as a general rule, if you wish to toggle DOM nodes, then I would go for a front-end approach, rather than rewriting the DOM server-side.

Comment: @Rounin Thanks, I agree. I'm just not sure using css classes only for the purpose of hiding/showing elements in this way is the correct way to do it, or there's a better existing mechanism, for example in angular I'd use `ngIf`.

Comment: From experience, I'd say that toggling a CSS class like `.show` / `.hide` is a pretty standard approach. An alternative (some would argue equivalent, others would argue cleaner) is to toggle the value of a custom `data-*` attribute, e.g. `data-display="show"` / `data-display="hide"`. Or - an even simpler alternative - toggle the presence of a single `data-hide` attribute.

Comment: If you want to toggle a class, you can use [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). If you want to toggle an attribute you can use [`Element.toggleAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute).